# In Google cloud environment. is there exists a tool like : SQL profiler?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Well. Actually we work with SQL Server database and a very useful tool for us is the SQL Server Profiler.

We are thinking about migrating all the databases to Google cloud, but we are wondering if there exists a tool like the SQL Server Profiler. Because we would like to have some monitor and trace all the transactions, queries, requests from some apps or API's.

We searched the Google cloud documentation, but to be honest, it is complicated to me. A lot of terms that I don't know.

I appreciate your time, thank you